# health condition and chronic health conditions

Tags: physical-health

Are the two sentences in bold contradictory? (Specially caused health conditions should include chronic and acute conditions.)

**Approximately 10 % –15 % of U.S.
(between 10 and 20 million) children are estimated
to have an ongoing physical health condition**
(Bramlett & Blumberg, 2008)*. Although most of
these conditions are relatively mild and interfere little
with a child’s usual activities, at least 10 % of children
with physical illness have symptoms severe enough
to have an impact on their daily lives (Bethell, Read,
Blumberg, & Newacheck, 2008)**.

**More than one quarter
of all U.S. children have a chronic health
condition**, a significant increase over the rate seen in
earlier decades, and a statistic that looms large for the
nation’s efforts to subdue rising health care costs
(Bramlett & Blumberg, 2008).

Friedman, H. S. (Ed.). (2011). The Oxford handbook of health psychology. Oxford University Press.‏

*Bramlett  ,    M.D.    ,  &      Blumberg  ,    S.J    .      (  2008  ).    Prevalence  of  children with special health care needs in metropolitan and micropolitan statistical areas in the United States  .       Journal of Maternal & Child Health, 12   ,    488  .

** Bethell  ,    C.D.    ,      Read  ,    D.  ,      Blumberg  ,    S.J.    ,  &      Newacheck  ,    P.W    .     (  2008  ).      What is the prevalence of children with special health care needs?  Toward an understanding of variations in fi ndings and methods across three national surveys  .       Journal of Maternal & Child Health, 12   ,    1  .

Comment: They seem to be, yes, presuming that "ongoing physical health condition" is the same as "chronic health condition" and 'children' refers to the same age group and 'U.S.' covers the same territorial area. Only way to tell is by reading the papers to see how they qualify it. Given the overlapping authors, presume the later publication to be the most accurate.

Comment: @ChrisRogers as you see its from "Oxford handbook of health **psychology**" and its related to the definition of "chronic health condition" which is a term in health psychology.

Comment: The fact that the passage came from a health psychology handbook doesn't necessarily make the context of the question fit this site. Physical health may affect people psychologically but the fact is the crux of the question is asking whether ongoing physical health conditions are considered chronic. This is therefore off-topic as it doesn't directly pertain to the subject area of this site

Comment: @ChrisRogers. Thanks for your explanation. you are right about the content of the question, but I think if we consider health psychology a branch of psychology, the question is psychological (at least as much as non-psychological (I don't know it is right or not)). First, cause it is psychologists' concern to know the concrete definition the term they have got from another branch originally. Indeed, we need health specialists for a complete answer, but its not their problem (asker side); and second, cause  psychologist may have a modified definition (answerer side).

Comment: *"it is psychologists' concern to know the concrete definition the term they have got from another branch originally"* - I agree with what you are saying, but you would need to speak to the physical health specialists to gain that information, hense the reason for taking it to Health.SE.  Although Health.SE is general, Health.SE likewise direct psychological and neurological questions to us at Psychology.SE

Comment: Oh, it's migrated, here you go :-)

Comment: Yeah, they don't let us to finish our argument. ;-)

Comment: Bramlett & Blumberg (2008) and Bethell, Read, Blumberg & Newacheck (2008) could be a number of papers.  Can you please edit your question to add details of what papers are referred to in the citations?  These should be found in the Friedman book you quoted from and it would help with context.

Comment: @ChrisRogers here you are :-)